# Toggling table cell background between Block and None

Tags: css

I'm using `style.display = "none"` to hide a table cell but when I then use `style.display = "block"` to reveal it again it has a transparent background whereas before I hide it it has a solid background. How can I unhide a cell such that the background remains solid?

(In the image below when I float over the other 'menu' items the light-blue highlight covers the whole cell, but on Cut, Copy & Paste it only highlights the words)

[image]

HTML:

```
<!--Popup Menu-->
<div id="popup" style='position: absolute; display: none; z-index: 20; box-shadow: 5px 5px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);'>
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 style='border: 2px solid black;'>
  <tr>
    <td class='popupitem' onClick="popupItem(1)" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"><img width=32 height=32 src='camera.png'><font style='position: relative; top: -8px;'> &nbsp; Attach photos</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="menuPhrase" >
    <td class='popupitem' onClick="popupItem(7)" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"><img width=32 height=32 src='phrase.png'><font style='position: relative; top: -8px;'> &nbsp; Insert a sentence</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='popupitem' onClick="popupItem(2)" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"><img width=32 height=32 src='clear.png'><font style='position: relative; top: -8px;'> &nbsp; Clear</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='popupitem' onClick="popupItem(3)" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"><img width=32 height=32 src='disc2.png'><font style='position: relative; top: -8px;'> &nbsp; Save changes</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="menuCut">
    <td class='popupitem' onClick="popupItem(4)" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"><img width=32 height=32 src='cut.png'><font style='position: relative; top: -8px;'> &nbsp; Cut</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="menuCopy">
    <td class='popupitem' onClick="popupItem(5)" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"><img width=32 height=32 src='copy.png'><font style='position: relative; top: -8px;'> &nbsp; Copy</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="menuPaste">
    <td class='popupitem' onClick="popupItem(6)" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='lightblue'" onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'"><img width=32 height=32 src='paste.png'><font style='position: relative; top: -8px;'> &nbsp; Paste</font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Show all menu items...
document.getElementById("menuPhrase").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("menuCut").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("menuCopy").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("menuPaste").style.display = "block";
if (fieldType=="droplist") {
 // Hide Phrase, Cut, Copy, Paste...
 document.getElementById("menuPhrase").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("menuCut").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("menuCopy").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("menuPaste").style.display = "none";
}
```

CSS:

```
td.popupitem {
 padding-top: 4px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-left: 4px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your markup so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Hope the added code helps

Answer (score 0):

try `style.display = "table-cell"` instead of block (I'm assuming you initially didn't change the default `display` value for `td`, which is `table-cell`)

Comment: I tried that but then I end up with all 3 bottom items on one row rather than on three separate rows.

Comment: I'm sorry, without seeing your markup/css I made assumptions that don't match - the code you've now posted will help

Answer (score 0):

try the following on that cell:

```
 border:0px;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.